# Prevent for duplicates Core data swift

Tags: swift, core-data, duplicates

I want to avoid duplication in my core data swift. I have a sense that it should be done in-app delegate, but I am not sure what has to change.

Here is my code when I add a new Item:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Bookmarks> = Bookmarks.fetchRequest()
    let bookmark = Bookmarks(context: context)
    if bookmarkButton.image == UIImage(systemName: "bookmark")  {
        bookmarkButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "bookmark.fill")
        bookmark.urlToImage = urlImage
        bookmark.source = sourceName
        bookmark.titleName = titleName
        bookmark.urlLink = url
        bookmarks.append(bookmark)

    } else {
        bookmarkButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "bookmark")
      
        if fetchRequest.predicate == NSPredicate.init(format: "titleName == %@", titleName!){
            print(bookmark)
            do {
                let objects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                for object in objects {
                    context.delete(object)
                }
                try context.save()
            } catch _ {
                // error handling
            }
            
        }
       
    }
    
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {

    }
}
```

Here is the photo of my application with duplication:

[image]

If you know anything about how to solve this problem help me out
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please stop posting the same question again and again. The question needs more information.  Post the code how and where you insert a new item. You have to check for a duplicate **before** you are going to insert a new item.

Comment: @vadian I got that I have to check before adding an item but I am asking how to check that item for existing? I looked up several websites but there not workable for my case

Comment: @BakhtovarUmarov you should not check if two images are equal. There is many ways to avoid that comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before inserting a new item check if an item with the same `titleName` already exists. If not insert the new item.

Something like this

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Bookmarks> = Bookmarks.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "titleName == %@", titleName!)
    
    if (try? context.fetch(fetchRequest))?.first != nil {
        bookmarkButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "bookmark.fill")
    } else {
        let bookmark = Bookmarks(context: context)
        bookmarkButton.image = UIImage(systemName: "bookmark")
        bookmark.urlToImage = urlImage
        bookmark.source = sourceName
        bookmark.titleName = titleName
        bookmark.urlLink = url
        bookmarks.append(bookmark)
    
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

If the item cannot be identified uniquely by the title add more conditions to the predicate.

Comment: yeah it helps for duplication but I wanted there also to context.delete(bookmark) if bookmarkButton.image == UIImage(systemName: "bookmark")